# Fortigate policy hierarchy - what does "ANY" actually mean?

Tags: firewall, fortigate

I've tried asking this in Fortinet's official forums yet no one knew the answer.

I have this in my Fortigate 100D:

> Port1(internal) -- > ANY interface -- > ANY service

I also have a route based IPSEC VPN.

My question is, why wouldnt data pass from Port1 to the tunnel this way?
Theoretically, doesnt it mean that my internal network should have permission to access all other interfaces?

I had to explicitly add:

> PORT1(internal) --> VPN1_INTERFACE -- > ANY service

and place it above the first rule in order to traverse the tunnel.

I might as well add that placing it below the first rule didnt work. Why is that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can think of is your local IP address gets NATed and sent to standard E-Gress interface instead of VPN interface